# Adding AWS Public url to Twilio's webhook address

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio

My Twilio Python with Flask and ngrok is working fine in terms of accepting calls and etc.  I am switching from ngrok to an AWS server.

Based on AWS my public DNS Address is -->

```
abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com  (This is a dummy address)
```

when I use that as an address in my twilio webhook (I tried all these)

```
http://abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xyz
http://abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xyz:5000
https://abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xyz
```

I get this error

```
Twilio was unable to fetch content from: http://abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com/abc
Error: Failed to connect to ip x.y.z.: connection timed out: ......
```

I also tried to open http://abc-12345.compute-1.amazonaws.com  in browser it didnt open

Comment: Have you updated the security group of your EC2 instance to allow access to the internet? Does your VPC have an internet gateway? Does the EC2 instance have a route table entry that send traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 to the Internet Gateway? Does the subnet that the EC2 instance is in contain Network Access Control List rules which block traffic?

Comment: That was my other problem because TWILIO does not provide a static IP address.-->   https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183868-Which-IP-addresses-will-Twilio-s-requests-come-from-
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015934048-All-About-Twilio-IP-Addresses Section REST API
The REST API's IP addresses are highly dynamic across a very large range, so it is not practical to whitelist based on IP addresses. Instead we recommend you allow all outbound HTTPS traffic to any .twilio.com subdomain.  For now I have two routes one for --> 0.0.0.0/0  and one for --> ::/0

Comment: "one for --> 0.0.0.0/0 and one for --> ::/0" What do the arrows signify? How does your EC2 instance know to allow traffic from the internet? If you yourself are unable to get a response from the endpoint then either your application is not properly configured or your security groups and VPC are not setup to allow the traffic.

Comment: are u using public hostnme or private hostname in the URL?

Comment: I use public hostname